# Laravel 4 form model and form open

Tags: forms, laravel, view, model

Why do I have to use always if statements in blade to check if there is a model in the view
and then open the form model or open a standard form?

Something like:

@if($model)

{{ Form::model($model, array('route' => 'foo')) }}

else

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'foo' }}

It could be just one Form::model instance in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{Form::model($model?:new MyModel, array('route' => 'foo')) }}
```

Comment: Or you just create de $model instance in the controller (empty instance or not)